# Get Max Value Attribut Using XPATH JDom

Tags: xml, jdom-2

I have a XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Table>
      <Etudiant Id="1">
        <Nom>Roberval</Nom>
        <Prenom>Roberval</Prenom> 
      </Etudiant>
      <Etudiant Id="2">
        <Nom>Roberval</Nom>
        <Prenom>Roberval</Prenom>            
      </Etudiant>
      <Etudiant Id="3">
        <Nom>Roberval</Nom>
        <Prenom>Roberval</Prenom>
      </Etudiant>
    </Table>
```

I need to select Max Attribut value Using JDom.here is the Java code

```
try {
   SAXBuilder saxeBuilde = new SAXBuilder();
   Document document =  saxeBuilde.build(new File("Data.xml"));
   Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
   List list = rootNode.getChildren("Etudiant");
   // need some code to get it
} catch(Exception) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage);
}
```

How to get Max id for Etudiant using XPath JDom?

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: My problem is, how to get Max id  for Etudiant using XPath JDom,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the attribute value of an xml node using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863038/how-to-get-the-attribute-value-of-an-xml-node-using-java)