# Retrieving Attribute Values from a XML string in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML string

```html
  <Result>
    <Component>PEV   CR</Component>
    <ComponentText xml:lang="pt-BR" />
    <ComponentText xml:lang="en-US">PEV   CR</ComponentText>
    <Item>CR_PEVPARA_BON BAD!</Item>
    <ItemText xml:lang="pt-BR">CR_PEVPARA_BON RUIM!</ItemText>
    <ItemText xml:lang="en-US">CR_PEVPARA_BON BAD!</ItemText>
    <ResultType>State</ResultType>
    <ResultText xml:lang="pt-BR" />
    <ResultText xml:lang="en-US" />
    <ResultState>NotOk</ResultState>
    <Type_State>
      <ActualString>0</ActualString>
      <ReferenceString>1</ReferenceString>
    </Type_State>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Component>NAV</Component>
    <ComponentText xml:lang="pt-BR" />
    <ComponentText xml:lang="en-US">NAV</ComponentText>
    <Item>ECU NO RESPONSE</Item>
    <ItemText xml:lang="pt-BR">SEM RESPOSTA UCE</ItemText>
    <ItemText xml:lang="en-US">ECU NO RESPONSE</ItemText>
    <ResultType>Execution</ResultType>
    <ResultText xml:lang="pt-BR" />
    <ResultText xml:lang="en-US" />
    <ResultState>NotOk</ResultState>
    <Type_Execution />
    <DetailTags>
      <Nack00.NackTextToTicket>Sem comunicacao UCE (00)</Nack00.NackTextToTicket>
      <Nack00.NackTextToStatistic>Nack: 0x7F 0x?? 0x00</Nack00.NackTextToStatistic>
    </DetailTags>
  </Result>
```

And I wanted to access, for example, the text inside this tag

```html
<ItemText xml:lang="pt-BR">SEM RESPOSTA UCE</ItemText>
```

Is there a library in Java that provides this functionality in a XPath fashion just like Selenium?

Comment: Is the XML constant or will change ? . I'm asking about the nodes,not the values

Comment: possible duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: JRE supports XPath 1.0, using Saxon 9 or 10 you can even use XPath 3.1. I would first worry about the lack of a root element that contains the `Result` elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the attribute value of an xml node using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863038/how-to-get-the-attribute-value-of-an-xml-node-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using jsoup, it pretty simple too. Please look at the comments in the code

Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Test Code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String s = "<Result>\r\n" + 
                "    <Component>PEV   CR</Component>\r\n" + 
                "    <ComponentText xml:lang=\"pt-BR\" />\r\n" + 
                "    <ComponentText xml:lang=\"en-US\">PEV   CR</ComponentText>\r\n" + 
                "    <Item>CR_PEVPARA_BON BAD!</Item>\r\n" + 
                "    <ItemText xml:lang=\"pt-BR\">CR_PEVPARA_BON RUIM!</ItemText>\r\n" + 
                "    <ItemText xml:lang=\"en-US\">CR_PEVPARA_BON BAD!</ItemText>\r\n" + 
                "    <ResultType>State</ResultType>\r\n" + 
                "    <ResultText xml:lang=\"pt-BR\" />\r\n" + 
                "    <ResultText xml:lang=\"en-US\" />\r\n" + 
                "    <ResultState>NotOk</ResultState>\r\n" + 
                "    <Type_State>\r\n" + 
                "      <ActualString>0</ActualString>\r\n" + 
                "      <ReferenceString>1</ReferenceString>\r\n" + 
                "    </Type_State>\r\n" + 
                "</Result>\r\n" + 
                "<Result>\r\n" + 
                "<Component>NAV</Component>\r\n" + 
                "<ComponentText xml:lang=\"pt-BR\" />\r\n" + 
                "<ComponentText xml:lang=\"en-US\">NAV</ComponentText>\r\n" + 
                "<Item>ECU NO RESPONSE</Item>\r\n" + 
                "<ItemText xml:lang=\"pt-BR\">SEM RESPOSTA UCE</ItemText>\r\n" + 
                "<ItemText xml:lang=\"en-US\">ECU NO RESPONSE</ItemText>\r\n" + 
                "<ResultType>Execution</ResultType>\r\n" + 
                "<ResultText xml:lang=\"pt-BR\" />\r\n" + 
                "<ResultText xml:lang=\"en-US\" />\r\n" + 
                "<ResultState>NotOk</ResultState>\r\n" + 
                "<Type_Execution />\r\n" + 
                "<DetailTags>\r\n" + 
                "  <Nack00.NackTextToTicket>Sem comunicacao UCE (00)</Nack00.NackTextToTicket>\r\n" + 
                "  <Nack00.NackTextToStatistic>Nack: 0x7F 0x?? 0x00</Nack00.NackTextToStatistic>\r\n" + 
                "</DetailTags>\r\n" + 
                "</Result>";
        
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);

        /*
            doc.select("ItemText") - this contains multiple "org.jsoup.nodes.Element" objects
         */
        System.out.println(doc.select("ItemText"));
        /* above line produces output:
         
                <itemtext xml:lang="pt-BR">
                 CR_PEVPARA_BON RUIM!
                </itemtext>
                <itemtext xml:lang="en-US">
                 CR_PEVPARA_BON BAD!
                </itemtext>
                <itemtext xml:lang="pt-BR">
                 SEM RESPOSTA UCE
                </itemtext>
                <itemtext xml:lang="en-US">
                 ECU NO RESPONSE
                </itemtext>
         */
        
        
        /*
            doc.select("ItemText").get(0) - this contains 1st element of ItemText
            But it prints whole of the element, Not just text
        */
        System.out.println(doc.select("ItemText").get(0));
        /* above line produces output:
         
                <itemtext xml:lang="pt-BR">
                 CR_PEVPARA_BON RUIM!
                </itemtext>
         */
        
        
        /*
            doc.select("ItemText").get(0).text() - this contains 1st element of ItemText
            It prints just the text the element holds
        */
        System.out.println(doc.select("ItemText").get(0).text());
        /* above line produces output:
         
                CR_PEVPARA_BON RUIM!
         */

    }

}
```