# Java XML - Can you jump down directly to a deep reference or do you have to iterate through?

Tags: java, xml

Take an XML document like the following, but imagine it more complex with additional Nodes and Children for each Node.

```
<Vehicles>
    <FourWheels>
      <Truck>
        <HeavyDuty>
          <Engine></Engine>
          <BedSize length="6.5"/>
          <Exterior>
            <Doors>
              <Door> FrontLeft
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="A"/>
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
              <Door> FrontRight             ///<------Door #2
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="A"/>
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
              <Door> BackLeft
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="A"/>
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
              <Door> BackRight
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="A"/>
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
            </Doors>
          </Exterior>
        </HeavyDuty>
        
        <LightDuty>
          <Engine></Engine>
          <BedSize length="5.5"/>
          <Exterior>
            <Doors>
              <Door> FrontLeft
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="A"/>
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
              <Door> FrontRight     ///<------Door #2
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="B"/>   ////<-----Check if type B
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
              <Door> BackLeft
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="A"/>
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
              <Door> BackRight
                <DoorDetails>
                  <InsidePanel>
                    <Locktype type="A"/>
                  </InsidePanel>
                </DoorDetails>
              </Door>
            </Doors>
          </Exterior>
        <LightDuty>
    </Truck>

    <Car>
        :
        :Same as above.
        :
    </Car>

    </FourWheels>
                
</Vehicles>
```

Keep in mind there could be numerous other Nodes and Children involved.

If the objective is to check the LockType on the ***2nd Door only***, is it possible to jump right down to that particular Door and LockType to see if the attribute is "A" or "B"?

Or will you have to traverse through each parent/child/child/child.... relationship to get down to the particular Node and check the attribute?

EDITED TO ADD CODE BASED ON RECOMMENDED REFERENCE.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class VehicleTest {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    VehicleTest test = new VehicleTest();
    test.readXML();
}

private void readXML()
{
    Document doc = null;
    try 
    {
        doc = parseXML("c:\\Downloads\\VehicleTest.xml");
    } 
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (SAXException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(doc != null)
    {
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Truck");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            Node nNode = nList.item(i);
            System.out.println("nNode : " + nNode);
            
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            System.out.println("eElement : " + eElement);
            
            Element cElement =  (Element) eElement.getElementsByTagName("HeavyDuty").item(0);
            System.out.println("cElement : " + cElement);   
            
            Element E2  =  (Element) cElement.getElementsByTagName("Exterior").item(0);
            System.out.println("E2 : " + E2);   

            Element E3  =  (Element) E2.getElementsByTagName("Doors").item(0);
            System.out.println("E3 : " + E3);   
            
            Element E4  =  (Element) E3.getElementsByTagName("Door").item(1); 
            System.out.println("E4 : " + E4);   
            
            Element E5  =  (Element) E4.getElementsByTagName("Locktype").item(0);
            System.out.println("E5 : " + E5);   

            System.out.println("LockType : " + E5.getAttribute("type"));
        }
    }
}

private Document parseXML(String filePath) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(filePath);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    return doc;
}
}
```

Output :

[image]

I will have to play around with this. Although it works, it only processed one of the Truck items and need to process both.

In the code I provided, using "HeavyDuty" would case an exception for the 2nd iteration as its only LightDuty.

Comment: Can you refer this ? it might be of some help. For example : you can directly do `doc.select("Doors")` to get all Doors objects and if there are multiple you can select elements like you do in an array. It uses jsoup as library

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693039/retrieving-attribute-values-from-a-xml-string-in-java/67694231#67694231

Comment: @Chandan, it a little more involved than this example because in my example, I would only want the Doors related to Trucks and not Cars. Using the above would bring back all references.

Comment: actually not very different. you have to do first select Truck and then Doors thats it like `doc.select("Truck").select("Doors")`

Comment: I just noticed you are referencing JSoup which I don't have and would not be able to install on the required machines.

Comment: I did take the code above in the Sample and applied it to my actual XML file and it worked nicely.